# Concurrency: Only one user editing an item at a time

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I've been researching how to fix this issue for sometime but can't seem to find a proper solution.

Here's the issue:

I have a Java EE application where many users can login, they are presented with an item list, and they can select and edit any one of those.

All users see the same item list.
As mentioned, they can edit an item but I'd like to restrict the editing function to one user. That is, many users can edit different items simultaneously but only one user can edit a particular item.

When one user is editing an item, an message should appear to any other user trying to edit that item.

I have implemented this by setting a flag on the item, inUse, to true and then check for that. When the user is done editing the item, either by clicking save or cancel, the flag is set to false. 
Problem with this approach is to account for cases when the user leaves his browser open or the browser is closed.

I tried setting a session timeout but can't seem to make that work because when the session times out, I don't have access to that item. I only have access to the httprequest session id.

Perhaps this is the wrong approach since it seems it's an issues that many applications would have and a less hackie solution should exist.

I looked into using threads and synchronized methods but don't know how that would work because once the user enters into the edit item screen, the method exits and releases the lock.

I found this solution [Only one user allowed to edit content at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153434/only-one-user-allowed-to-edit-content-at-a-time) but not sure if that's the way to go in Java.

Is there a more elegant/java solution? If so can you point me in the right direction please? How would you implement this?

Thanks!

The solution:
Although originally I thought optimistic locking was the way to go, I quickly realized that it wouldn't really work for my environment. I decided to go with a combination of pessimistic locking (http://www.agiledata.org/essays/concurrencyControl.html#PessimisticLocking) and timeouts.

When an item is accessed, I set an inUse field to true and the object's last accessed field to the current time.

Everytime when somebody tries to edit the object, I check the inUse field and the lastAccessed field + 5 mins. So basically, I give 5 mins to edit the user.

Comment: Where do you store the association between an editing user and its edited item? Why can't you access the item from the session listener?

Comment: The item object has a field inUse and that's all I was updating. The httpSession only stores http session related. Hence, can't access it reliably

Comment: OK. So, once the user posts the form which allows editing the item, where do you find the item to edit? Why don't you store the list of items edited by the user in the session (or in database)? You could easily switch the to not-in-use when the session times out.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into optimistic locking.

Comment: I used optimistic locking method and it works beautifully. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

Do it like they do in a database, where a timestamp is used. The timestamp is kept with the record and when a person submits his edit, the edit does not go through unless the timestamp is the same (meaning 'no edits have occurred since I read this record'). Then when the edit does go through, a new timestamp is created.

Comment: That is optimistic locking. The OP wants pessimistic locking.

Comment: @Mark Robbins can you please explain how to initialize timestamp? I mean if there are 2 users who want to edit the item how would you distinguish that first user has already locked the item?

Comment: I believe @Mark is referring to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153434/only-one-user-allowed-to-edit-content-at-a-time

Comment: @user1161661 the author has already mentioned it in the post, so he aware of it

Comment: My example is optimistic locking, but pessimistic locking can be achieved by giving away a timestamp that expires, and only allowing updates from that timestamp.

Comment: @Mark, can you further explain how a timestamp that expires would be implemented? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your persistence layer, you really should be doing [*optimistic locking*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control), using a version/timestamp field.

At a UI level, to handle your use case I would do *resource leasing*:

1. Add two fields to your table:

   - `LAST_LEASE_TIME`: Time of the last lease
   - `LAST_LEASE_USER`: User that leased the record for the last time.
2. When a user tries to edit your record, first check that the record is not leased,  or that the lease has expired (that is, the lease is not older that the specified lease time) or that the user is the one that was granted the lease.
3. From your web browser, periodically renew the lease, for example with an AJAX call.
4. When the user ends editing the record, explicitly expire the lease.

By doing leasing, you solve the "closed browser" problem: after the lease period expires without any lease renovation, the algorithm automatically "releases" the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use : [Session Beans](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/EJBConcepts3.html) Quote:

In general, you should use a session bean if the following circumstances hold:

At any given time, only one client has access to the bean instance.
The state of the bean is not persistent, existing only for a short period of time (perhaps a few hours).

Answer (score 0):

Martin Fowler describes 4 patterns for such a problem:

1. Online Optimistic Locking
2. Online Pessimistic Locking
3. Offline Optimistic Locking
4. Offline Pessimistic Locking

You should decide which one to use according to your problem.
JPA, JDO and Hibernate provide 1 and 2 out of the box.
Hibernate can handle 3 too, (I'm not sure about JPA and JDO).
None handle 4 out of the box and you shall implement it yourself.

Comment: This is interesting, because it describes all the possible strategies, but you should provide a link to the description of all those strategies.